# Is Firebug lying to me?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug, plupload

I have an Object in my javascript called `file`. Running `console.log(file)` allows me to inspect the object in Firebug like so...

[image: firebug]

Here is the problem: when I try to access `file.status` I get `0`. `file.name` and the other attributes all work fine... it is just `status` that outputs `0` no matter what.

Any ideas what is going on???

BTW, this object is a plupload File object, if that matters. Also, the Webkit Inspector produces the same results.

Thanks!

Comment: Where's the code that you are using?

Comment: Question title made me laugh. Made me think: _Is my debugger cheating on me?_

Comment: Of course Firebug isn't lying to you. Unless _I_ am lying to you about Firebug lying to you...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is the security around JavaScript that prevents sharing the details.  It is not lying, but not telling you things.  Good JavaScript, another citizen protected.

Java security can make it hard to manipulate the files ahead of time as well, thus why there are so many uploader utilities, ok and because of IE7-9 not supporting multi-file browser selection.  Example Y[UI Uploader](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/uploader/) or [SWFUploader](http://swfupload.org/).

Answer (score 0):

interesting, if I had this mystery and wanted to get to the bottom of it - I would have either read the code that creates and manipulates this object, or try to use different javascript enumerations to see what I can get from this object.

Maybe a `for in` loop, just to see where it gets me. After all, many javascript dev tools were built using javascript - they shouldn't have more insight on objects than regular js commands.